# Can't make serverside axios api call behind a firewall

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, axios

I'm looking into axios to use for some node.js http calls to APIs while inside a corp firewall - and i'm falling down at the first hurdle.

I found an example that uses axios to do a server http call below

```
const axios = require('axios');
const API = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('api works');
});

// Get all posts
router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
  // Get posts from the mock api
axios.get(`${API}/posts`, { proxy: { host: 'http://proxy.com', port: 8080}})
//axios.get(`${API}/posts`)
    .then(posts => {
      res.status(200).json(posts.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error)

    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

but when i'm behind the firewall i get an error below

> // http://localhost:3000/api/posts
>
> {
>   "code": "ENOTFOUND",
>   "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
>   "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
>   "hostname": "http://proxy.com",
>   "host": "http://proxy.com",
>   "port": 8080,
>   "config": {
>       "transformRequest": {
>
> ```
> },
> "transformResponse": {
>
> },
> "timeout": 0,
> "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
> "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
> "maxContentLength": -1,
> "headers": {
>   "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
>   "User-Agent": "axios/0.15.3",
>   "host": "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
> },
> "method": "get",
> "proxy": {
>   "host": "http://proxy.com",
>   "port": 8080
> },
> "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
> ```

it works find when i switch to a direct connection to the internet and the proxy setting are what i use for npm - i'm not sure if the final solution will be inside or outside of the firewall but i can't figure out to do this either specific to this api or even globally just for dev.. any help would be appreciated..

Comment: anyone else able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that axios just wants the host in the proxy config, not the URL with protocol:

```
"proxy": {
  "host": "proxy.com",
  "port": 8080
}
```

Comment: anyone else able to solve this?